# Session_scope raises attribute error when using Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, contextmanager

I have tried to implement the session scope from the sqlalchemy session documents but for some reason I am getting a attributeerror:*exit*  at      with session_scope as session:

The code looks like this:

```
@contextmanager
def session_scope():
 """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
 session = Session()
 try:
     yield session
     session.commit()
 except:
     session.rollback()
     raise
 finally:
    session.close()



class SearchPhoneTable():
 def DateSearch(self,session,StartDate,EndDate):
    DateValue=[]
    OrderValue=[]
    SessionResult=session.query(VideoChange).filter(and_(VideoChange.Date <= EndDate, VideoChange.Date>=StartDate)).all()
    for elements in SessionResult:
        DateValue.append(elements.Date)
        OrderValue.append(elements.ViewsValue)
    return DateValue,OrderValue


def PDFOnline2(StartDate,EndDate):

 with session_scope as session:
  Xaxis,Yaxis=SearchPhoneTable().DateSearch(session,StartDate,EndDate)


 for elements in Yaxis:
    print(elements)

 for elements in Xaxis:
    print(elements)


 return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, you just need to call the context manager function:

```
with session_scope() as session:
```

Notice the parentheses.